# How to relate 2 collections in MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, mongodb, express

I have 2 collections, actor and movie, in these models I have fields
actors: {type: [{}], ref: 'Actor'} and movies: {type: [{}], ref: 'Movie'}
and my question is how can I connect them between each other?
For example, if I have list of actors, how should I add them to actors Array from Movie model automatically?
Here 2 full codes of models

Actor model

```
import mongoose, {Schema, model, connect, Types} from 'mongoose';

const actorSchema = new Schema<IActor>({
    nameRus: {type: String, required: true},
    nameEng: {type: String, required: true},
    totalMovies: {type: Number, required: true},
    img: {type: String, required: true},
    shortBio: {type: String, required: true},
    bio: {type: String, required: true},
    fullBio: {type: String, required: true},
    reviews: {type: [{}], ref: 'actorReview'},
    // reviews: [String],
    movies: {type: [{}], ref: 'Movie'},
}, {timestamps: true});

export interface IActor extends mongoose.Document{
    id: string,
    nameRus: string,
    nameEng: string,
    totalMovies: number,
    img: string,
    shortBio: string,
    bio: string,
    fullBio: string,
    reviews?: Types.Array<string>,
    movies?: Types.Array<Object>,
    _doc?: any
}

export default mongoose.model('Actor', actorSchema);
```

Movie model

```
const movieSchema = new Schema<IMovie>({
    title: {type: String},
    shortDesc: {type: String},
    fullDesc: {type: String},
    audioLyrics: String,
    posterImg: {type: String},
    titleImg: {type: String},
    rating: {type: String},
    totalStars: {type: Number, default: 0,},
    starNumber: {type: Number, default: 0,},
    year: {type: String},
    country: {type: String},
    duration: {type: String},
    typeOfMovie: {type: String}, //its family or any else
    ageLimit: {type: String},
    language: {type: String},
    trailer: {type: String},
    video: {type: String},
    reviews: {type: [{}], ref: 'movieReview'},
    // reviews: [String],
    genre: {type: String},
    originalTitle: {type: String},
    releaseDate: {type: String},
    director: {type: String},
    actors: {type: [{}], ref: 'Actor'},
    // actors: [String],
    producers: [String],
    screenWriters: [String],
    operators: [String],
    quality: [String],
    isCartoon: {type: Boolean, default: false}
}, {timestamps: true});

export interface IMovie extends mongoose.Document{
    id: string,
    title: string,
    shortDesc: string,
    fullDesc: string,
    audioLyrics: string,
    posterImg: string,
    titleImg: string,
    rating: string,
    totalStars: number,
    starNumber: number,
    year: string,
    country: string,
    duration: string,
    typeOfMovie: string,
    ageLimit: string,
    language: string,
    trailer: string,
    video: string,
    reviews?: Types.Array<Object>,
    genre: string,
    originalTitle: string,
    releaseDate: string,
    director: string,
    actors: Types.Array<Object>,
    producers: Types.Array<string>,
    screenWriters: Types.Array<string>,
    operators: Types.Array<string>,
    quality: Types.Array<string>,
    isCartoon: boolean,
    _doc?: any
    reverse?: any
}

export default mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);
```

Can anybody help to solve this problem?
I tried populate method but it doesn't seems to work

Comment: Why not `$lookup` the actors in movies or vice versa? https://mongoplayground.net/p/98SMfL--hqE